# Converting python fibonacci code to java?

Tags: java, python, fibonacci

So here is the python code:

```
def fib(n):
  ## Handle special case when n == 0
  if n == 0:
    return 0
  ## General case, return the first of the
  ## two values returned by fibaux
  else:
    return fibaux(n)[0]

## Auxiliary function
## Return the nth and (n-1)th Fibonacci numbers
## n must be an integer >= 1
def fibaux(n):
  ## Base case of for recursion
  if n == 1:
    return 1, 0
  else:
    ## Recursive case
    f2, f1 = fibaux(n - 1) ## **this is the part I cant figure out in java**
    return f2 + f1, f2
```

The ** part of the code (f2, f1 = fibaux(n - 1)) is not right in my java code.here is the java code:

```
public static int[] fib(int number){
  if (number == 0){
     return new int[] {0};
  }
  else{
     int fibauxArray[] = fibaux(number);
     int f3 = fibauxArray[0];
     return new int[] {f3};
  }
}

public static int[] fibaux(int number){
  if (number == 1){
     return new int[] {1, 0};
  }
  else{
     int[] Q = fibaux(number-1);
     int[] R = fibaux(number-1);
     int f2 = Q[0] + R[0];
     int f1 = Q[0];

     return new int[] {f2, f1};
 }
```

in python, f2 and f1 are different values, but in my java code Q[] and R[] are the same value, so it does not calculate the right result.I do not understand how to make this work? Thank you!

Comment: Why are you returning a single value in an array? Also, where did `R` come from?

Comment: If you just want to translate the Python into Java, you should keep the same organization, eg public static int fib(int number) -- return a number for the two cases, not arrays and there is no need for Q and R, just use one result from the recursion, like you do in the Python.

Comment: I was treating Q[] like f2 and R[] like f1 from the python code. And yeah, you are right, the fib() function does not need to return an array.

Comment: I dont understand @C S, if I get rid of Q[] and R[] it always results in 1?

Comment: @Jessica looks like someone has posted a complete solution, but I'd think about it on your own first before looking at it, as it seems clear you don't understand the Python code to begin with.  You're having fibaux return two consecutive Fibonacci values, which you then manipulate to return two values.  In Python, "return x,y" is basically the same as the Java "return new int[] {x,y}".  There's no reason to call fibaux twice in the Java code when the only real difference is the way you return two values.

Comment: For me this code isn't clear. You should return n-1 on first index and n on second. Then it will be more clear. Of course U need to make few other changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
public static int fib(int number){
  if (number == 0){
     return 0;
  }
  else{
     int fibauxArray[] = fibaux(number);
     return fibauxArray[0];
  }
}

public static int[] fibaux(int number){
  if (number == 1){
     return new int[] {1, 0};
  }
  else{
     int[] Q = fibaux(number-1);
     int f2 = Q[0];
     int f1 = Q[1];

     return new int[] {f2+f1, f2};
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but when I do this it always returns a 1, any idea why?

Comment: nevermind, you have to make f2 Q[1] and f1 Q[0] for it to work for me.

Comment: return new int[] {f2+f1, f1}; should be better

Comment: +1 for being an exact conversion of the Python code. It is however an inefficient, memory-wasting way for doing recursive Fibonacci in Java. --- Well, ok, to be exact, it should be `return fibaux(number)[0];` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Pair` class:

```
class Pair {
    private int first;
    private int second;
    // getters, setters, constructor
}
```

This part:

```
def fib(n):
  ## Handle special case when n == 0
  if n == 0:
    return 0
  ## General case, return the first of the
  ## two values returned by fibaux
  else:
    return fibaux(n)[0]
```

can be "translated" to:

```
int fib(int n) {
  // Handle special case when n == 0
  if (n == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  // General case, return the first of the
  // two values returned by fibaux
  else {
    return fibaux(n).getFirst();
  }
}
```

And this part:

```
## Auxiliary function
## Return the nth and (n-1)th Fibonacci numbers
## n must be an integer >= 1
def fibaux(n):
  ## Base case of for recursion
  if n == 1:
    return 1, 0
  else:
    ## Recursive case
    f2, f1 = fibaux(n - 1) ## **this is the part I cant figure out in java**
    return f2 + f1, f2
```

to:

```
// Auxiliary function
// Return the nth and (n-1)th Fibonacci numbers
// n must be an integer >= 1
Pair fibaux(int n):
  // Base case of for recursion
  if (n == 1) {
    return new Pair(1, 0);
  } else {
    // Recursive case
    Pair next = fibaux(n - 1);
    return new Pair(next.getFirst() + next.getSecond(), next.getFirst());
  }
}
```

([Demo](https://ideone.com/mSE4vn))

Answer (score 0):

fibaux returns array element n in index 0 and n-1 in index 1.

Do not execute fibaux twice. Just use result of the first execution.

So you should do it this way..

```
else{
int[] Q = fibaux(number-1);
int f2 = Q[1] + Q[0];
int f1 = Q[0];
return new int[] {f2, f1};
```